# Comparing instances of derived classes having the same parent class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, comparison, derived-class, typeof

I have two classes extendending the same parent class, like this:

```
class ParentClass{ ... }
class Son extends ParentClass{ ... }
class Daughter extends ParentClass{ ... }
```

I'd like to have code similar to this pseudocode:

```
a.getClass() === b.getClass();
```

which should only return true if both variables are instances of the same derived class (e.g. `Son` or `Daughter` in this example).

Comment: Do you mean `instanceof`? Because `typeof` doesn't give you the class, it only gives you the base *type*. As in `"string"`, `"number"`, `"object"`, `"function"` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to have code similar to this:
>
> ```
> typeof a === typeof b
> ```
>
> which only returns true if both variables are instances of the same derived class (e.g. `Son` or `Daughter` in this example).

No, that returns true if `a` and `b` are objects of **any** kind, including ones completely unrelated to `ParentClass`, because `typeof` will be `"object"` for any object, and of course, `"object" === "object"` is true.

`instanceof` returns `true` if the left-hand operand's prototype chain contains the object referenced by the right-hand operands `.prototype` property, so `instanceof` will work as you describe you seem to want:

```
a instanceof ParentClass === b instanceof ParentClass
```

Live Example:

```js
class ParentClass { }
class Son extends ParentClass { }
class Daughter extends ParentClass { }

const a = new Son();
const b = new Daughter();

console.log(a instanceof ParentClass === b instanceof ParentClass); // true

const c = new Son();
const d = new Map(); // Not a ParentClass subclass

console.log(c instanceof ParentClass === d instanceof ParentClass); // false
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> I'd like to find out if two variables are instances of the same derived class. My original question was worded very confusingly, so I edited it.

Ah, then you'd want to use the `constructor` property in one of two ways. Either:

1. To see if `a` is an instance of the same class as `b` *or a subclass* of `b`'s class:

   ```
   a instanceof b.constructor
   ```
2. To see if `a` is an instance of the same class as `b`:

   ```
   a.constructor === b.constructor
   ```

The `constructor` property comes from the instance's prototype; by default, it's a reference to the cosntructor function the prototype object was originally attached to *(that is, `Son.prototype.constructor` refers to `Son`).

Live example of #1:

```js
class ParentClass { }
class Son extends ParentClass { }
class Daughter extends ParentClass { }

const a = new Son();
const b = new Daughter();

console.log(a instanceof b.constructor); // false

const c = new Son();
const d = new Son();

console.log(c instanceof d.constructor); // true

class SonSubClass extends Son { }

const e = new SonSubClass();
const f = new Son();

console.log(e instanceof f.constructor); // true
```

Live example of #2:

```js
class ParentClass { }
class Son extends ParentClass { }
class Daughter extends ParentClass { }

const a = new Son();
const b = new Daughter();

console.log(a instanceof b.constructor); // false

const c = new Son();
const d = new Son();

console.log(c instanceof d.constructor); // true

class SonSubClass extends Son { }

const e = new SonSubClass();
const f = new Son();

console.log(e.constructor === f.constructor); // false
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to find out if two variables are instances of the same derived class. My original question was worded very confusingly, so I edited it.

Comment: @Hade0011 - Ah! I've added to the answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect!

Comment: @Hade0011 - I just realized that the answer didn't address subclasses, so I've clarified that part. You'll either want `a instanceof b.constructor` or `a.constructor === b.constructor` depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to determine if two arbitrary objects share a common ancestor you need to compare the prototypes of both recursively.

I wrote a function that can take two things of `unknown` type and will tell you if they ever shared a common ancestor:

```js
function sharesParent(sibling: unknown, possibleSibling: unknown): boolean {
    if (sibling !== null && possibleSibling !== null) {
        const objectPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf({});
        const functionPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Function);
        let currentSiblingPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(sibling);

        while (currentSiblingPrototype !== objectPrototype && currentSiblingPrototype !== functionPrototype) {
            let currentPossibleSiblingPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(possibleSibling);

            while (currentPossibleSiblingPrototype !== objectPrototype && currentPossibleSiblingPrototype !== functionPrototype) {
                if (currentPossibleSiblingPrototype === currentSiblingPrototype) {
                    console.log(currentPossibleSiblingPrototype);
                    return true;
                }

                currentPossibleSiblingPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentPossibleSiblingPrototype);
            }

            currentSiblingPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentSiblingPrototype);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

class Rock { }
class Granite extends Rock { }
class Limestone extends Rock { }

class Animal { }
class Panda extends Animal { }
class Horse extends Animal { }

class Pony extends Horse { }

console.log(
    sharesParent(new Pony, new Granite) /* false */,
    sharesParent(new Panda, new Pony) /* true */,
    sharesParent(new Pony, new Horse) /* true */,
    sharesParent("string", "secondString") /* true */,
    sharesParent("string", 42) /* false */,
    sharesParent(Map, Set) /* false */,
);
```

If you know what shared ancestor you are looking for it is a lot better to use `instanceof` as proposed by T.J. Crowder.

Comment: @AlpeinWorldCup: Thanks. I don't want to know if two variables' classes share the same ancestor. I want to know if they are instances of exactly the same class. Comparing two instances of `foo` should return `true`. Comparing `foo` and  `bar` should return  `false` even if `foo` and  `bar` both extend the same class.

Comment: @Hade0011 If that is the case then it is exactly what `sharesParent` does. Have you tried it? Did it work?